# openshif cloudcomputing configuration,is possible complete on cloud?

Tags: scala, hadoop, openshift, bigdata

Is possible build a bigdata application on cloud with RED HAT'PaaS OpenShift? I'm looking how build on cloud an Scala Application with Hadoop (HDFS),Spark,an Apache Mahout but i can't find any thing about it.I've seen something with HortonWorks but nothing clear about how install it in an openshift environment an how add HDFS node in Cloud too.Is it possible with OpneShift?

It's possible in Amazon   but my question is : IS possible in OpenShift ??

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you're ultimately trying to achieve. I know you mention building a big data application on Openshift with Scala but what will the application ultimately be doing?

I've gotten Hadoop running in a gear before but if you want a better example check out this quickstart here to get an idea of how its done https://github.com/ryanj/flask-hbase-todos. I know its not scala but here's a good article that will show you how to put together a scala app https://www.openshift.com/blogs/building-distributed-and-event-driven-applications-in-java-or-scala-with-akka-on-openshift.

Answer (score 0):

What will the application ultimately be doing?:
Forecasting for football match result for several football leagues,a web application (ruby) and 
statistic computation and data mining ,calculations with Scala language 
and apache frameworks(spark & mahout).
We get the info via CSV files, process and save it in nosql db (Cassandra).
And all of this on cloud(OpenShift),that's the idea.

I've seen the info https://github.com/ryanj/flask-hbase-todos.I'll try by this way but 
with Scala.